# What is CCM -- Counter Mode Cipher Block Chaining Message Authentication Code Protocol

Tags: cbc, ccm, wpa2-psk

CCM puts together two different modes of operation (at least in the name). Does it mean data is encrypted using counter mode and then encrypted using CBC; kind of a double encryption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CCM puts together two different modes of operation (at least in the
>   name). Does it mean data is encrypted using counter mode and then
>   encrypted using CBC; kind of a double encryption?

**Yes, kinda.**
With the [CCM mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode), you authenticate your data first using [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC) which is, well, basically [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC) on the data to be authenticated.

Now on the combination of ciphertext and tag you apply the [CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) to conceal the contents. While you do "double-encryption" here, you only send the full result of the CTR mode and only the very last block from the CBC mode (encrypted using CTR). The latter one is the tag with which the recipient can verify the integrity of the message.

Comment: Is a meet in the middle attack a threat to the double encryption in this case?

Comment: @Minaj, well, sure. But CCM never claimed to reach better security than each component provides so there's no point in doing one (to break security guarantees)

Comment: This is not an implementation of double-encryption. This is not $E(k_1, E(k_2, m))$. It is $E(k_1, m) || f(E(k_2, m))$ (where $f$ is just taking the last block). There is no "middle" to meet in here.